# why this function not work in create BinTree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want create this BinTree .[image]
in this function it can't work.

```
typedef struct BinNode {
    Elemtype data;
    struct BinNode* left;
    struct BinNode* right;
}BinNode,*BinTree;
void createBinTree(BinTree* root, char* a) {
    if (*a == '\0')
        return;
    if (*a == '#') {
        (*root) = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else {
        (*root) = (BinTree)malloc(sizeof(BinNode));
        assert((*root) != NULL);
        (*root)->data = *a;
        createBinTree(&(*root)->left, ++a);
        createBinTree(&(*root)->right, ++a);
        return;
    }

}
int main() {
    char* ptr = "ABC##DE##F##G#H##";
    BinTree my_tree = NULL;
    createBinTree(&my_tree,ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to run this function,It doesn't create the correct BinTree like in the picture。
but this way can.

```
void createBinTree(BinTree* root, char** a) {
    if (**a == '\0')
        return;
    if (**a == '#') {
        (*root) = NULL;
        (*a)++;
        return;
    }
    else {
        (*root) = (BinTree)malloc(sizeof(BinNode));
        assert((*root) != NULL);
        (*root)->data = **a;
        (*a)++;
        createBinTree(&(*root)->left, a);
        createBinTree(&(*root)->right, a);
        return;
    }
}
int main() {
    char* ptr = "ABC##DE##F##G#H##";
    BinTree my_tree = NULL;
    createBinTree(&my_tree,&ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

why it can. i don't understand why call  createBinTree need pass **&ptr** but **ptr.**please help me!

Comment: OT: don't hide pointer types behind typedefs. If I see `BinTree foo;`, I have no idea that `foo` is actually a pointer. If I see `BinNode *foo;` it is perfectly clear that `foo` is a pointer.

Comment: OK，Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 2):

In the first program the value of the pointer `a` in the second call of the function

```
createBinTree(&(*root)->right, ++a);
```

is not equal to the last value of the pointer `a` after the first call of the function

```
createBinTree(&(*root)->left, ++a);
```

Consider for example the initial processing of the string.

In the first call of the function there is passed the pointer `a` that points to the character `'B'`.

In the second call of the function there is passed the pointer `a` that points to the character `'C'` instead of pointing to the character `'#'`.

In the second program the pointer `a` is passed by reference through a pointer to it. So after the first call of the function the value of the pointer `a` will be the last value of the pointer after the first function call.

Comment: Can I understand it that way?because when the recursive call ends and returns to the previous level, the value of **'a'** remains the same as the one saved at this level, rather than being updated with a new value.during the second call when **'B'** is passed, although the left subtree has been successfully created, when attempting to create the right subtree, the value of **‘a’** remains the same as the one passed for the creation of the left subtree, which is **'B'**.right？

Comment: @Ly丶Cooki As the pointer a s passed by value then each recursive call of the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer. The original pointer stays unchanged.  When the pointer is passed by reference through a pointer to it then dereferencing the pointer to pointer the function can change the original pointer.

Comment: "Okay, I understand. Thank you very much."